# automatic span width

Tags: html, css

I have following HTML for a heading. The `.left` and `.right` are empty spans. I have specific width for the .left and but the `.text` width is not always same. I want to set the background for the .left (fixed width) and the `.right`. The `.right` should get all the remaining space in the parent element (h1). How that can be done?

```
<h1>
    <span class="left"></span>
    <span class="text">Text</span>
    <span class="right"></span>
</h1>
```

I'm trying following CSS which does not work:

```
.left{
    background: yellow;
    width: 30px;
    height: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.right{
    display: inline-block;
    background: blue;   
}
```

Here's the JSFiddle link: 
http://jsfiddle.net/jMR8u/

Here's what I'm trying to get:[image]

The idea is to set a background image in h1 except the `.text` span and the problem is that I can not set the background for the .text, otherwise it would be easier.

Comment: I can't understand what you are trying to do, could you maybe draw an image of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: "The `.right` [span] should get all the remaining space in the parent element (h1)."

Comment: @daniel I added the image. I know it would be easier if I could set bg for h1 and then set bg for the .text span, but the problem is that I can not set bg for .text (because it should use the background of the body)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i interpret your image correct .. this is the answer http://jsfiddle.net/jMR8u/4/

```
h1{
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: relative; 
}

.left{
    background: yellow;
    width: 30px;
    height: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.right{
    display: inline-block;
    background: blue;
    position: absolute; 
    z-index: 99;
    height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}
​.text {
    height: 20px;
    width: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    z-index; 101;
}​
```

ok, then use layers .. with z-index and positioning

Comment: Because the .text should use the same background of the h1 parent bg.

Comment: This way is the easier. If you can't act inside the H1, then act outside ... add a div surrounding the H1 with a colored background and set your H1 with white background and left/right margin ?

Answer (score 2):

**This version will stretch to fit the contents of `.text` and should be cross-browser.**

You can fake the blue (right) background by making it a border of `.text`:

```
.text { border-right: 1000px solid; }
```

Then, shift `.right` to the left by 1000px:

```
.right { margin-left: -1000px; }
```

Give a width to `.left`, make each element `inline-block`, hide the extra blue border on the right, and make sure `.text` and `.right` do not wrap to a new line:

```
.left { width: 200px; }
.left, .text, .right { display: inline-block; }
h1 { overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; }
```

And give it color!

```
body { background: green; }
.left { background: red; }
.text { border-color: blue; }
```

Here is a JSFiddle [demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/GNsqN/):

[image: Screenshot from the JSFiddle]

Comment: Thanks Andres for the nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could use flexbox (but use the [new syntax](http://css-tricks.com/old-flexbox-and-new-flexbox/)). Sadly, it only works on [Chrome and Opera](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) for now, so this has limited usefulness:

```
h1 { display: -webkit-flex; display: flex; }
.left { width: 30px; }
.right { flex: 1; -webkit-flex: 1; } /* This makes it fluid. */
.left { background: yellow; }
.right { background: blue; }
```

Here is a JSFiddle demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/FN7vQ/

Comment: This is exactly what I'm trying to get, but I need the major browsers support (at least FF)

Comment: See my [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13733816/237285) for a more compatible solution.

Answer (score 1):

if you can set width to the .text span and h1 element.

```
body{
background:green;
}

h1{
    border: 1px solid red;
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}

.left{
    background: yellow;
    width: 30px;
    display: table-cell;
}

.right{
    display: table-cell;
    background: blue;
}
.text {
    display:table-cell;
    width: 150px;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your requirement correctly. you should change your markup a little bit as below

```css
h1 {
  background: #660000;
  padding-left: 30px;
  line-height: 1.1;
}
h1 span {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 3px;
  color: #600;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  <span>
  Lorem, ipsum dolor. you are doing great  
  </span>  
</h1>
```

and CSS goes here below